# "end kernel panic not syncing" Error after upgrade Ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: kernel, updates, 18.04

Today I have updated my Ubuntu Desktop from 16.04 to 18.04. After that I was getting loging loop issue. The I have tried the steps mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/223634/424425). Then I was able to login. But after restart I am getting "**end kernel panic not syncing**" issue and unable to login to system.

Please help me to resolve this issue. I am not so much technical. So, it will be helpful if you share the solution is details and step wise.

If required then I can fresh install 18.04. But I wan to ensure the data. So, if no solution is available then please share me the steps in details to install the Ubuntu in fresh with data.